# How to fix spacing

Tags: spacing

This system of equations comprise of a sequence of equations and I want to use the horizontal dots to skip the intermediate equations much like in 1,2 ...n. But when I do the following there is an ugly space/gap before the equal sign, plus the horizontal dots `\ldots` don't fill the length of the equation. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

% here
\begin{equation}
    \systeme{
        L_i^TS_1 = 0,
        L_i^TS_2 = 0,
        \ldots,
        L_i^TS_{i-1} = 0
    }
\end{equation}
% to here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what you'd like to fix? Also, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG Thank you for the suggestion, it has been fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest `\cdots` for better vertical spacing. You can enclose it in `\mathllap` to get rid of the unwanted space. Note: `\mathllap` requires the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}

\begin{document}

% here
\begin{equation}
    \systeme{
        L_i^TS_1 = 0,
        L_i^TS_2 = 0,
        \mathllap{\cdots},
        L_i^TS_{i-1} = 0
    }
\end{equation}
% to here

\end{document}
```

You might consider `\vdots`:

[image]

To have horizontal dots go across the whole line, you can use `\dotfill`. I suggest raising it for better spacing:

`\rlap{\raisebox{.5ex}{\makebox[1.8cm]{\dotfill}}}`

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the dots to be longer to fill the entire length of the equations

Comment: I added this to my answer.